# laravel livewire filter not refreshing merchandise list

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm currently new to livewire and I have a problem in filtering my merchandise list depending on the category. I created a merch-filter component with checkboxes for categories.

Some code inside my merch-filter.blade.php. Don't mind the onChange, it's a function for only allowing 1 checked box.

```
            <label>
               <input class="cb" 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    wire:model="category" 
                    wire:click="filter" 
                    value="pre-order" 
                    onchange="cbChange(this)"><span>PRE-ORDER</span>
            </label>
            <label>
               <input class="cb" 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    wire:model="category" 
                    wire:click="filter" 
                    value="onhand" 
                    onchange="cbChange(this)"><span>ON-HAND</span>
            </label>
```

merchfilter.php. I emit the $category to my merch-container component.

```
class MerchFilter extends Component
{
    public $category = "";

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.merch-filter');
    }

    public function filter() {
        $this->emitTo('merch-container', 'reload', $this->category);
    }

}
```

some code inside my merch-container.blade.php

```
@foreach($merchandise as $merch)
<div class="col-lg-4 px-5 py-2" >
    <div class="row d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img 
            class="d-block w-100" 
            src="{{URL::asset('/storage/merchandises/'.$merch->image)}}" style="height:250px;"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 500">{{strtoupper($merch->name)}}</p>
    </div>
```

And finally my merchcontainer.php

```
class MerchContainer extends Component
{

    public $merchandise;
    protected $listeners = ['reload'];


    public function mount() {
        $this->merchandise = Merchandise::all();
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.merch-container');
    }

    public function reload($category) {
        $this->merchandise = Merchandise::query();

        if ($category) {
            if ($category === 'all-products') {
                $this->merchandise = Merchandise::all();
            } else {
                $this->merchandise = Merchandise::where('category', $category)->get();
            }
        }
        
        return view('livewire.merch-container');
    }


}
```

Please help me solve this problem, I have searched everywhere and followed different ways in doing this, still cant find anything. I already tried to dd($this->merchandise) before the return view inside my reload function and it returns the correct merchandise. The only problem is, in the view, it is not refreshing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that the filter is correctly set up and configured. It should be connected to the list of merchandise and sending the correct parameters to the server.

If the filter is set up correctly, then try adding a Livewire:Refresh command to the filter. This will force the page to reload when the filter is used, refreshing the list of merchandise.

If that still doesn't work, then you may need to add a manual page refresh command when the filter is used. This can be done by adding a JavaScript event listener to the filter that triggers a page reload when the filter is modified.
This is how we managed this issue at https://customnia.com